# How to delete product share from a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a product share between app admin and sales rep in my apex trigger. Now I want to delete the product share from that code. How do i do it?

Code as below:
    the code which i tried is as below:

```
trigger createDeleteShare on Product_Territories__c (after delete) {

 Map<String,String> m_thId_gId = new Map<String,String>();
   for (Product_Territories__c pt : trigger.new ) {        
       m_thId_gId.put(pt.Ref_Territory_Hierarchy__c, null);
   }

 Map<Id,Territory_hierarchy__c> m_thId_th = new Map<Id,Territory_Hierarchy__c> (
           [select Id, TerritoryId__c from Territory_Hierarchy__c where id in :m_thId_gId.keyset() ] );

 Map<String,String> m_tId_thId = new Map<String,String>();
   for (Territory_Hierarchy__c th : m_thId_th.values() ){
       m_tId_thId.put(th.territoryId__c, th.Id);
   }

 List<Group> groupList= [select Id, relatedId from Group where type='TerritoryAndSubOrdinates' and relatedId in :m_tId_thId.keySet()];
   for (Group g : groupList) {
     String tId = g.relatedId;
     String thId = m_tId_thId.get(tId);
     m_thId_gId.put (thId, g.Id);
   }

  List<Product__Share> psList = new List<Product__Share>(); 
  for(Product_Territories__c pt: psList) { 
     psList= [select Id Name from Product_Territories__c where GroupId =      m_thId_gId.Id];
  } 

   delete psList; 

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the product share from that code"? Do you want to manually want delete the product share relationship?

Comment: Yes i want to drop the product share link between the two users

Comment: This code is for after insert. I want to write the code for after delete trigger

Comment: sorry total code was not copied correctly. My code is the same as you edited. I want to write a similar code for after delete so that it drops the product share

Comment: Can you please be more specific at the issue/s that you're having? Or you're looking for someone to write the trigger for you?

Comment: actually this is the trigger created for after insert. when i asked my sir about it he said that after delete is also same as this code but we need to change the last pslist and write a code to delete the share instead of adding the list. I tried to apply many logics but i didnt get the output so if u can please help me out in bulding up the logic i would be grateful

Comment: i want the code for after delete

Answer (score 0):

In after delete trigger you will have to query for all products share with product id in trigger.new and user/groupId equal to your existing logic on how you get your user or group id and say delete in bulk.

Comment: I believe it's trigger.old when trigger runs before/after delete...

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't understand what you said can you explain me and i have been trying the code for 4 days and i'm unable to write the code

Comment: i even tried trigger.old but i got an error. I dont exactly remember what the error was

Comment: Can you post the error here!

Comment: i dont have the code i deleted it

Comment: the code was List<Product__Share> psList = new List<Product__Share>();  for(Product_Territories__c pt: psList)  { psList= [select Id Name from Product_Territories__c where GroupId = m_thId_gId.Id];  }  delete psList;

Comment: Whats the error you got ?

Comment: Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'm_thId_gId.Id' at line 29 column 77

Comment: the code which i tried is as below:

trigger createDeleteShare on Product_Territories__c (after delete) {
    
     Map<String,String> m_thId_gId = new Map<String,String>();
       for (Product_Territories__c pt : trigger.new ) 
       {        
           m_thId_gId.put(pt.Ref_Territory_Hierarchy__c, null);
       }
   
     Map<Id,Territory_hierarchy__c> m_thId_th = new Map<Id,Territory_Hierarchy__c> (
               [select Id, TerritoryId__c from Territory_Hierarchy__c where id in :m_thId_gId.keyset() ] );
     
     Map<String,String> m_tId_thId = new Map<String,String>();

Comment: continuation:  for (Territory_Hierarchy__c th : m_thId_th.values() )
       {
           m_tId_thId.put(th.territoryId__c, th.Id);
       }
   
     List<Group> groupList= [select Id, relatedId from Group where type='TerritoryAndSubOrdinates' and relatedId in :m_tId_thId.keySet()];
       for (Group g : groupList) 
       {
         String tId = g.relatedId;
         String thId = m_tId_thId.get(tId);
         m_thId_gId.put (thId, g.Id);
       }

Comment: continuation: List<Product__Share> psList = new List<Product__Share>(); 
      for(Product_Territories__c pt: psList) 
      { 
         psList= [select Id Name from Product_Territories__c where GroupId = m_thId_gId.Id];
      } 
      
      delete psList; 
    
}   this was my code for delete and im getting the error as mentioned above what is wrong in this please let me know

Comment: @mounica can you add all code in your question.Its difficult for me to go through each and scan this .

Comment: I changed the code above. That was the code i tried for delete and my error was Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'm_thId_gId.Id' at line 29 column 77

Comment: Change this line `psList= [select Id Name from Product_Territories__c where GroupId = m_thId_gId.Id];` to `Set <Id> gIds = new Set <Id> (); gIds.addAll(m_thId_gId.values()); psList= [select Id Name from Product_Territories__c where GroupId IN :gIds];`